# web and integrated wordpress or create web with wordpress

Tags: web, wordpress

I would like to create a website with a blog. The website will have multiple languages.

I would like to know which option will be better:

- Create a website and integrate wordpress in it.
- Install wordpress and use plugins to have more than 1 language.

  I have strong knowledge in web programming (php, js, html). But not with wordpress. The website will be standard.

Is it easier to use wordpress plugins or do a website and install multiple wordpress in it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to run Wordpress and use a language plugin. [WPML](http://wpml.org) is the best I've used. Stay away from qTranslate since it'll be a mess if you want to uninstall it. I've heard some good about [Ploylang](http://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) but never used it myself.

Wordpress is really easy to learn if you're a web developer.